# Sum columns by last 6 months in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a pretty big table in `Sqlite` like this,

```
A          |          B          |       time   (Current system time milisecond)
___________________________________________________________________________________________
2                     3                 3376333000000 
4                     6                 2123423430000
2                     4                 2334324234000
```

I want an result having 6 rows that represents data of last 6 months, where I'll precisely get

SUM(A) , SUM(B) , Time like "SEP'14" where "SEP'14" represents SUM(A) and SUM(B) for SEPTEMBER 2014. Next rows will have the summations of data of those columns for Month AUGUST 2014 , JULY 2014 and so on. A sample output is as follows

```
SUM(A)     |      SUM(B)          |       month
_____________________________________________________________
5                     7                 SEP'14 
4                     8                 AUG'14
6                     4                 JUL'14
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: it's unclear how to interpret `time` field

Comment: time field represents data for column A and B for a day. Say, today my value for A is 2 and B is 3. So, database entry will be , 2,3,currentSystemTime .

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the time stamp to a year/month and then use `group by`:

```
select strftime(date(time / 1000, 'unixepoch'), '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       sum(A), sum(B)
from table t
group by strftime(date(time / 1000, 'unixepoch'), '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm desc
limit 6;
```